# Java AWT: How to vertically center checkbox with flow layout next to label inside panel with gridlayout?

Tags: java, checkbox, awt, grid-layout, flowlayout

I am writing a little program with Java AWT.

I have a panel with GridLayout (2 columns). On the left side of the panel is a Label, on the right side a CheckboxGroup.

The CheckboxGroup is in FlowLayout. It doesn't appear on the same height as the Label. How can I adjust the height/vertically center my CheckboxGroup?

I've tried to wrap the CheckboxGroup(with FlowLayout) in a BorderLayout and set it to BorderLayout.CENTER/SOUTH.

```
Panel panelSelector = new Panel(new GridLayout(0,2,3,3));

HotTubLabel = new Label("Hot Tub option:");
    panelSelector.add(HotTubLabel);
    HotTubInput = new CheckboxGroup();
    Panel panelHotTubCheck = new Panel(new FlowLayout());
    panelHotTubCheck.add(new Checkbox("Yes", HotTubInput, false));
    panelHotTubCheck.add(new Checkbox("No", HotTubInput, false));
    panelHotTubCheck.add(new Checkbox("No preference", HotTubInput, true));
    panelSelector.add(panelHotTubCheck);
```

I expect the CheckboxGroup line to be on the same height as the Label line, just as it is with all the other objects like choice, TextField or Label.

Here a picture: [Link to the picture because I don't have enough reputation ^^](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vu4rx.png)

EDIT: Fixed the alignment by using GridLayout for the CheckboxGroup but now GridLayout stretches the CheckboxGroup over the whole length of the program and cuts "No preference" down to "No pr.." in the default program size.

See this picture: [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeO2n.png)

I would like them to display like with FlowLayout before but vertically aligned.

EDIT 2: Here is a minimal reproducible example of the initial problem:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ChaletSelectorExample1 extends Frame {

  private Label HotTubLabel;
  private CheckboxGroup HotTubInput;

  public ChaletSelectorExample1(){

    Panel panelSelector = new Panel(new GridLayout(0,2,3,3));

    HotTubLabel = new Label("Hot Tub option:");
    panelSelector.add(HotTubLabel);
    HotTubInput = new CheckboxGroup();
    Panel panelHotTubCheck = new Panel(new FlowLayout());
    panelHotTubCheck.add(new Checkbox("Yes", HotTubInput, false));
    panelHotTubCheck.add(new Checkbox("No", HotTubInput, false));
    panelHotTubCheck.add(new Checkbox("No preference", HotTubInput, true));
    panelSelector.add(panelHotTubCheck);

    setLayout(new BorderLayout(3, 3));
    add(panelSelector, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
      @Override public void windowClosing(WindowEvent evt) {
        System.exit(0);
      }
    });

    setTitle("ChaletSelectorExample1");
    setSize(500, 500);
    setVisible(true);  

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      new ChaletSelectorExample1();
  }

}
```

And here is a minimal reproducible example of the problem with the text being cut off after fixing the initial problem:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ChaletSelectorExample2 extends Frame {

  private Label HotTubLabel;
  private CheckboxGroup HotTubInput;

  public ChaletSelectorExample2(){

    Panel panelSelector = new Panel(new GridLayout(0,2,3,3));

    HotTubLabel = new Label("Hot Tub option:");
    panelSelector.add(HotTubLabel);
    HotTubInput = new CheckboxGroup();
    Panel panelHotTubCheck = new Panel(new GridLayout(0,3,0,0));
    panelHotTubCheck.add(new Checkbox("Yes", HotTubInput, false));
    panelHotTubCheck.add(new Checkbox("No", HotTubInput, false));
    panelHotTubCheck.add(new Checkbox("No preference", HotTubInput, true));
    panelSelector.add(panelHotTubCheck);

    setLayout(new BorderLayout(3, 3));
    add(panelSelector, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
      @Override public void windowClosing(WindowEvent evt) {
        System.exit(0);
      }
    });

    setTitle("ChaletSelectorExample2");
    setSize(500, 500);
    setVisible(true);  

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      new ChaletSelectorExample2();
  }

}
```

This is what I would like it to look like (and then all the other options that I want to include on top or below of course): [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tu7j.png)

Comment: 1) Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT components in favor of Swing. 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 3) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used.

Comment: 1) AWT just to practice that first. 2) Thanks for the advice I added the minimal reproducible examples. 3) Also added a concept of the intended layout of the GUI

Comment: *"1) AWT just to practice that first."* Nobody uses, and few people will help with problems related to,  AWT components. Go direct to Swing.

Comment: Well thats good to know too ^^ will do.